# How do I pass a reference to a d3 element to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, splunk

I have an element which I can manipulate through "d3.select(this.$el).append('svg')", my question is how do I make it possible to do the same manipulation in a called function?

I'm new to d3 and jquery and have just worked through this tutorial from Splunk, which uses both: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.3/AdvancedDev/CustomVizTutorial.

The problem arises when I try to move the creation of the svg into a separate function.  Here's my update view function:

```
    updateView: function(data, config) {
        // Return if no data
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }

        // Assign datum to the data object returned from formatData
        var datum = data;

//START BIT THAT WORKS
        // Clear the div
        /*this.$el.empty();

        // Get color config or use a default yellow shade
        var mainColor = config[this.getPropertyNamespaceInfo().propertyNamespace + 'mainColor'] || '#f7bc38';

        // Set meter max value or use a default
        var maxValue = parseFloat(config[this.getPropertyNamespaceInfo().propertyNamespace + 'maxValue']) || 100;

        // Set height and width
        var height = 220;
        var width = 420;

        // SVG setup
        var svg  = d3.select(this.el).append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .style('background', 'white')
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        // Text
        svg.append('text')
            .datum(datum)
            .attr('class', 'meter-center-text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .style('fill', mainColor)
            .text(function(d){
                return "0";
                //return parseFloat(d);
            });*/
//END BIT THAT WORKS

        newFunc=function(myElement) {
            console.log("newFunc");

            // Clear the div
            myElement.empty();

            // Get color config or use a default yellow shade
            mainColor='#f7bc38';

            // Set meter max value or use a default
            maxValue=1000000;

            // Set height and width
            var height = 220;
            var width = 420;

            // SVG setup
            var svg  = d3.select(myElement).append('svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .style('background', 'white')
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

            // Text
            svg.append('text')
                .datum(datum)
                .attr('class', 'meter-center-text')
                .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .style('fill', mainColor)
                .text(function(d){
                    return "100";
                });
        };
        newFunc(this.$el);
    }
```

The first half is the code from the tutorial, this works as expected (it's commented out above).

The second half is me replicating this code in a new function, for simplicity's sake here it's just an inner function.

This produces the error "this.ownerDocument is undefined", which I've narrowed down to being caused by the "d3.select(myElement).append('svg')" line.

So my question is, what is the correct way to pass in the reference to this element and work on it within the function?

Comment: this.$el is set in an earlier function: "this.$el = $(this.el);", I can post the whole file if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Right now you're trying to pass a *jQuery object* as the argument of `newFunc`. However, `d3.select` accepts only a string (selector) or a DOM element.

According to the D3 API, `d3.select`:

> Selects the first element that matches the specified selector **string**. If the selector is not a string, instead selects the specified **node**. (emphases mine)

Let's see this in the first snippet. There is a `<div>` in the body, with `myDiv` as the ID. If we select that div with jQuery...

```
var elem = $("#myDiv");
```

... you'll have an jQuery object. According to the jQuery API:

> When creating new elements (or selecting existing ones), jQuery returns the elements in a collection. Many developers new to jQuery assume that this collection is an array. It has a zero-indexed sequence of DOM elements, some familiar array functions, and a .length property, after all. Actually, the **jQuery object** is more complicated than that. (emphasis mine)

Here is the snippet, have a look at the two `console.log`, comparing them:

```js
var elem = $("#myDiv");
console.log(elem[0]);
console.log(elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

As you can see, you **cannot** pass `$(foo)` to a function as an argument to `d3.select`.

However, you can pass `$(foo)[0]`, which is the node.

Here is a second snippet to show this. I'm using most of your code, but passing `$("#myDiv")[0]` to `newFunc`:

```js
newFunc = function(myElement) {

  // Get color config or use a default yellow shade
  mainColor = '#f7bc38';

  // Set meter max value or use a default
  maxValue = 1000000;

  // Set height and width
  var height = 220;
  var width = 420;

  // SVG setup
  var svg = d3.select(myElement).append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .style('background', 'white')
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

  // Text
  svg.append('text')
    .datum("foo")
    .attr('class', 'meter-center-text')
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .style('fill', mainColor)
    .text(function(d) {
      return "100";
    });
};
var elem = $("#myDiv");
newFunc(elem[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

PS: Since we don't have a jQuery object anymore, I removed `myElement.empty();`.

PPS: Please, **don't mix D3 and jQuery**. It makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry about the mixing of D3 and Jquery - that's how it came from Splunk!  I see, so I can pass in the node, and then if I want to empty it I'd do d3.select(myNode).empty?  Or is empty a jquery command, in which case I'll need to do $(myNode).empty?

Comment: `empty` is a jQuery method. There is an `empty` in D3, but it's different.